# QDomElement conversion

Tags: mysql, qt, qtxml

I receive a `xml` stanza, for instance, like the following in my server app:

```
<iq from='stpeter@jabber.org/roundabout'
   id='v1'
   type='get'>
   <vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/>
</iq>
```

e.g `enclosed in QDomeElement object in client's side` and sent to server.
Hence, I'm trying to save the current xml in `QDomElement` object in `text` format in database. And when extracted from DB, and convert it to QDomElement? How can I do this?

Comment: Save it as XML (text)? Though that's a bad idea if you ever want the database to "understand" the data (search based on it etc), in that case you should put it in as proper database data (rows, columns, tables), and then generate the DOM from database data when needed.